# Modify an Android app to only work for a specific device

Tags: android, locking, device, imei

is there an easy way (other than doing code stuff), an android app that could modify an android app to only work for a specific device? I've been working on modding a specific app that took me a long time to perfect but I want to share it to anyone I wanted to but there might be a risk it could be spreaded anywhere. I've read something here about IMEI number which is a great idea but I'm such a noob so I'm asking if anybody might know if there's such an app that could do this without typing such codes? Thanks

Comment: if you only want a specific few people using it, you can consider uploading it to the playstore and perhaps just distributing it under a closed testing track

Answer (score 0):

android.os.Build class has all the information about the phone.

```
if(android.os.Build.DEVICE != "Name of device you want"){
   exit(0);
}
```